# How to extend Thymeleaf dialect with existing fragment template

Tags: java, spring, templates, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf fragment with a lot of internal logic (around 500 lines of template code with loops and conditions) that creates a data table for some project requirements. As of now, I have to write the following line in order to use this fragment anywhere in my templates:

`<th:block th:replace="ecobase/components/framework/dataGrid.html :: content( dataSource = ${dataSource} )"/>`

Which means that I have to keep my template (`dataGrid.html`) somewhere in my templates folder. So I was wondering if it was possible to simplify this to something like this:

`<div custom:grid="${dataSource}"/>`

and with the usage of a custom dialect replace it with my custom table. So the only problem is that AFAIK I'd have to rewrite the whole 500-line thymeleaf template in Java code to put the result into `structureHandler.setBody()` in my processor.

The question is if there is a solution to somehow import my existing html template to the processor (from classpath maybe) and process it and then put into the tag with custom attribute?